SQL Max over partition based on a column
hope you are doing well
I need to calculate the total number of rows (children) that a package has
input data
StartDate  EndDate    PlanSystemId  Package_Id  Package_Type    month   mode    rnumber 
2024-03-19 2024-04-14 93167253       null        Package       2024-04  null      1          
2024-03-19 2024-04-14 93170470       93167253    Child         2024-04  MENSUEL   2 
2024-03-19 2024-04-14 93170471       93167253    Child         2024-04  MENSUEL   3 
2024-03-19 2024-04-14 93167253       null        Package       2024-03  null      1          
2024-03-19 2024-04-14 93170470       93167253    Child         2024-03  MENSUEL   2 


In the month 2024-04 the package (plansystemid 93167253) has 2 childs
In the month 2024-03 the package (plansystemid 93167253) has 1 child

output data
PlanSystemId    Package_Id  Package_Type    month    mode   rnumber number_childs
93167253         null        Package       2024-04   null         1          2
93167253         null        Package       2024-03   null         1          1

I have this query, maybe you can help to improve it. If you have a better option please let me know.
Thanks in advance
WITH CTE_parent_child AS (
SELECT 
  Startdate, EndDate,PlanSystemId,Placement_code,
  Package_Id,Package_Type,month,mode,
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month, IFNULL(Package_Id,PlanSystemId ) ORDER BY PlanSystemId ) AS rnumber

FROM table
WHERE (package_type = 'Package' or package_type='Child') 
  AND (PlanSystemId = 93167253  or Package_Id = 93167253) 
)
SELECT 
  Startdate,EndDate, PlanSystemId, Package_Id,
  Package_Type,month, mode,rnumber,
  MAX(rnumber) over(partition by month, Package_Id ORDER BY PlanSystemId ) as number_childs
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN Package_Type = 'Child' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY month, Package_Id) AS number_childs

FROM CTE_parent_child
ORDER BY month,plansystemID,IFNULL(Package_Id,PlanSystemId ) desc;


If performance matters, the better solution is to not use NULL, use its own id (such that the parent and the children all have the same package_id). Then COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY month, package_id) - 1 will be both concise and performant.

Why are there the same systemids?

You could use Count() Over() analytic function conditioned by case expression:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl ( STARTDATE,  ENDDATE,    PLANSYSTEMID,  PACKAGE_ID,  PACKAGE_TYPE,    A_MONTH,   A_MODE,    RNUMBER ) AS
        ( Select DATE '2024-03-19', DATE '2024-04-14', 93167253,  null,        'Package',  '2024-04',  null,       1  From Dual Union All 
          Select DATE '2024-03-19', DATE '2024-04-14', 93170470,  93167253,    'Child',    '2024-04',  'MENSUEL',   2  From Dual Union All  
          Select DATE '2024-03-19', DATE '2024-04-14', 93170471,  93167253,    'Child',    '2024-04',  'MENSUEL',   3  From Dual Union All 
          Select DATE '2024-03-19', DATE '2024-04-14', 93167253,  null,        'Package',  '2024-03',  null,       1  From Dual Union All 
          Select DATE '2024-03-19', DATE '2024-04-14', 93170470,  93167253,    'Child',    '2024-03',  'MENSUEL',   2  From Dual 
        )

--    S Q L :
SELECT  *
FROM    ( Select  PLANSYSTEMID, PACKAGE_ID, PACKAGE_TYPE, A_MONTH, A_MODE, RNUMBER,
                  Count(Case When PACKAGE_TYPE = 'Child' Then 1 End) 
                      Over(Partition By COALESCE(PACKAGE_ID, PLANSYSTEMID), A_MONTH) as NUMBER_CHILD
          From    tbl 
        )
WHERE    PACKAGE_TYPE = 'Package'
ORDER BY PLANSYSTEMID, A_MONTH Desc

/*     R e s u l t :
PLANSYSTEMID PACKAGE_ID PACKAGE_TYPE A_MONTH A_MODE     RNUMBER NUMBER_CHILD
------------ ---------- ------------ ------- ------- ---------- ------------
    93167253            Package      2024-04                  1            2
    93167253            Package      2024-03                  1            1  */


Instead of the case expression, you could just add -1 after the count...

You can directly count childrens by subquery.
See example
SELECT Startdate, EndDate,PlanSystemId,
   Package_Id,Package_Type,month,mode
 ,(select count(*) from test_table t2 
   where t2.package_id=t.plansystemid and t2.month=t.month
  ) as childs_count
from test_table t
where package_id is null

demo
with test_table as( 
  select cast('2024-03-19' as date) StartDate ,cast('2024-04-14' as date) EndDate, 93167253 PlanSystemId, cast(null as int)  Package_Id ,'Package' Package_Type,'2024-04' month,cast(null as string)mode, 1 rnumber
union all select '2024-03-19','2024-04-14', 93170470,93167253,'Child',  '2024-04','MENSUEL', 2
union all select '2024-03-19','2024-04-14', 93170471,93167253,'Child',  '2024-04','MENSUEL', 3
union all select '2024-03-19','2024-04-14', 93167253,null    ,'Package','2024-03',  null   , 1
union all select '2024-03-19','2024-04-14', 93170470,93167253,'Child',  '2024-03','MENSUEL', 2
   )
SELECT 
  Startdate, EndDate,PlanSystemId,
  Package_Id,Package_Type,month,mode
,(select count(*) from test_table t2 
  where t2.package_id=t.plansystemid and t2.month=t.month) childs_count
from test_table t
where PlanSystemId = 93167253
--  for all packages 
-- package_id is null 

example
